# how to make an element fill the table row

Tags: html, css

I have an element `<select> </select>` with some `<option> </option>` in a table row. I want this select to fill all the row space cause some other `<input type = "text">` make the row larger than the initial `<select>` width.

Here is my code to show you the space gap :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type = "text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option value = "option1" >value 1</option>
                <option value = "option2" >value 2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If you copy this code you will clearly see the difference between this element. How can I do to make them at the same width please ?

Comment: We could call this design-by-democratic-vote !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the simplest case, add a width to the `select` element:

```css
td {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  }
select {
  width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type = "text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option value = "option1" >value 1</option>
                <option value = "option2" >value 2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add `width: 100%` to select element:

```css
table tr td select{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type = "text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option value = "option1" >value 1</option>
                <option value = "option2" >value 2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the width of `<select>` to `100%` as follows:

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
select{
 width:100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type = "text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option value = "option1" >value 1</option>
                <option value = "option2" >value 2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can set the element width in css like this:

```
input, select {
    width : 100px;
}
```